# Can you generate relationships with Symfony (using Doctrine)?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, relational-database

At the moment, if I do the following, it just generates the schema.yml:

> ./symfony doctrine:build-schema

But that doesn't generate the relationships.

Do I have to manually add those into the schema.yml or is there a way to generate them? And if I have to manually enter it in, won't they be over-written next time I do a `doctrine:build-schema` (to refresh the schema with new tables, etc)?

Here is the schema.yml:

```
Companies:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: companies
  columns:
    company_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    company_name:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
          unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    company_logo:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    company_date_added:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
Credentials:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: credentials
  columns:
    credential_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    credential_name:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    company_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    credential_date_added:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
Groups:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: groups
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    group_name:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    company_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    group_date_added:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
GroupsCredentials:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: groups_credentials
  columns:
    group_credential_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    credential_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    group_credential_date_added:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
Users:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: users
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_username:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_password:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_email:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    company_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_date_added:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
UsersCredentials:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: users_credentials
  columns:
    user_credential_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    credential_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_credential_date_added:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

Comment: It should generate the relationships. Where are they missing? In the Base* files? or in your data/schema.sql file? Could you show us at least one relation in your schema.yml that does not work?

Comment: I updated the code and added the schema. Non of the relations are generated when I do `./symfony doctrine:build-schema`, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the relationships are set up correctly in the database? `./symfony doctrine:build-schema` creates the schema.yml file automagically based on what's in your database... maybe it's getting tripped up on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue.

The relationships weren't setup properly in the MySQL DB - stupid mistake on my part.